# Does local.oplog.rs hold all data in mongodb replication?

Tags: backup, mongodb

I'm trying to do backup full and incremental backup, I wonder does local.oplog.rs collecitons `contain all info that I need` to do backup and incremental backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB oplog is a special [capped collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) including all data used for replication. The oplog alone only includes an idempotent log of data changes. You can use the oplog for incremental backup and point-in-time restoration for a replica set, but note that an oplog backup is only valid to apply against an existing full data backup of the same replica set with a common oplog entry.

If you want to backup the `oplog.rs` collection independent of the rest of the data files you will have to use `mongodump`, which can have a significant effect on a production deployment as all of the oplog data needs to be read into memory by `mongodump`.  The `oplog.rs` collection also has a special caveat on indexing: it is designed to be scanned in `$natural` order and does not support adding any indexes.

A typical incremental backup approach for a production system is using [filesystem snapshots](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/#back-up-with-filesystem-snapshots) assuming your deployment (and filesystem) meet the requirements for a consistent backup. Filesystem snapshots capture the changes since the last snapshot, so are incremental after the first snapshot. Ongoing snapshots are less impactful for an active deployment than `mongodump`.

Another common approach is using agent-based backup (for example, MongoDB Cloud Manager or MongoDB Ops Manager). Agent-based approaches generally also use the oplog for real-time backup. See [Cloud Manager Backup Preparations](https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/core/backup-preparations/) for some background.

The MongoDB manual is the best reference for [supported backup methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/) for your version of MongoDB server. Backing up using `mongodump` for the oplog alone is not a recommended (or documented) backup method.

Comment: Thanks, I have additional question that is what would be minimal/least backup user permissions to do `mongodump` oplogs? I grant readonly role on all dbs but still can't `mongodump` oplogs.

Comment: @TuyenPham There's a `backup` role which includes all necessary permissions. See: [Backup and Restoration Roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#backup-and-restoration-roles).

Comment: Reading it but don't understand much, in my case I don't use agent, I'm trying to use `mongodump` to get incremental oplogs, what would be the needed roles to backup and restore in this case? and what is `non-system collections`? Does `local` is system collection?

Comment: Per the `backup` role description: "This role provides sufficient privileges ... to use `mongodump` to back up an entire mongod instance." (the same role works for agents). In addition to being able to read data, a full backup has to be able to list databases, collections, and indexes. There is also a built-in [`restore` role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#restore) which includes perms needed to restore from backup. As per the note there, you will need to add user permission for `anyAction` on `anyResource` to restore an oplog backup using `--oplogReplay`.

Comment: I have this comand to create user: `use mydb
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "backupuser",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "backup", db: "mydb" } ]
  }
)`. In `roles` option I specify `[ { role: "backup", db: "mydb" } ]`, does it enough to do backup with `backupuser` I created as above?

Comment: @TuyenPham If you are having trouble setting up required roles for backup & restore, the details would be better as a separate question including your specific version of MongoDB server, `mongodump` command-line, and any error messages or outcomes. If you want to backup the oplog your user should be created in the `admin` database; oplog data includes all databases. The role suggested in your previous comment is limited to `mydb` which is insufficient scope for oplog access.

Comment: Thanks, I have created a user as below: `use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "backup",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "backup", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
` and tested locally, it does backup job successfully, is that is correct user for backup job? Many thanks.